# Enable Aspera HTTP fallback with HAProxy

Tags: proxy

If UDP is blocked, i need to enable HTTP(s) fallback with aspera connect plugin thru HAProxy.  Has anyone successfully done this ?   I have read all the documentation but there is nothing that describes the HAProxy use case

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about a client side forward proxy.

If you use the IBM Aspera Connect Client, it comes with HTTP (forward) proxy configuration.

http://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/connect/3.9.6/user_osx/webhelp/index.html#dita/network_environment.html

This will work when the client falls back to HTTP.

Note that the client will fallback to HTTP only if this feature is enabled on the server side.

You can see that by examining the parameters provided to the client by the browser (put in dev mode). In that case, it has http parameters (port).
Typically, parameter: https_fallback_port

If not, then there is no possible http fallback, and it will not use the (forward) proxy.

If you are talking about reverse proxy in front of a server configured with fallback, this is part of the (public) documentation of the IBM Aspera Proxy.